# Regular expression in C# match when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, expression, python-re

I'm writing some code, where I want to let me say normalize url. In the first step I want to get the root of the url. I'm using regular expression for that goal. I'm using following code.

```
string unifiedURL = Regex.Replace(url, @"^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w-]+\.[\w-]{2,6})", "$3");
```

Regular expression should match anything which has protocol on begining optional www. and anything consist from word character plus minus sign followed by mandatory dot and two to six word character. But when I debug my code then it copies input to output. When I type asi input (url variable) something like "asd asd asd". It shouldn't do so.

I verified it at the website https://regex101.com/

I tried it with the following input strings (in the variable url)

`asda adad asda; adsaadada`

and I got the same output in both cases. I would expect empty string. I'm not able to resolve that. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why not use the `System.Uri` class? As long as you're giving it a valid URI, it can handle parsing out the relevant elements.

Comment: I would go with the suggestion by @DanielMann. Use the built in `System.Uri` to do this. It will even tell you if the string is a valid URI. Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The point of this question is not how to check url. I have problem with regular expression. Regex.Replace(string1, string2, string3) should apply re in string2 to string1 and return string3. So when it doesn't match, it should return empty string as return parameter $3 should be empty. So it is not correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my mistake. I expected different behavior. It is correct functionality. I read the definiton of that function and I have to say, that it works as defined. Can I find, whether input string (url in my case) match the pattern?

Comment: Please don't write additional questions in the answers sections. Instead, you can edit the original post and add more details there.